# JSP - Load an image

Tags: jsp

I have a problem with my img tag on my jsp file, the image can't load :

```
  <img src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/images/book.jpg"/>
```

I had another solution but didn't work too.

```
  <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/book.jpg" />
```

My IDE (IntelliJIdea) doesn't see a problem about the path, here is a screenshot about my file

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I0Vd.png)

Comment: you should write this line `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` on console and check the root if it is true

Comment: first thing is make sure that your jsp file placed inside web folder then `request.getContextPath()`  or `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` should return current project name which you are running on server